# Numpy apply along axis based on row index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

Trying to apply `numpy` inbuilt function `apply_along_axis` based on `row index position`

```
import numpy as np
sa = np.array(np.arange(4))
sa_changed = (np.repeat(sa.reshape(1,len(sa)),repeats=2,axis=0))
print (sa_changed)
```

OP:

```
[[0 1 2 3]
 [0 1 2 3]]
```

The function:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x+10,0,sa_changed)
```

Op:

```
array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 12, 13]])
```

But is there a way to use this function based on `row index position` for example, if its a `even row index` then `add 10` and if its a `odd row index` then `add 50`

Sample:

```
def func(x):
   if x.index//2==0:
      x = x+10
   else:
      x = x+50
   return x
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a speed tool.  It can make code look prettier, especially if the array is 3d or larger, but it doesn't do things faster.

Comment: By the way, `//` is integer division, not modulus

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the solution. Do you have any other suggestions for faster approach? Not exact code, just suggestions would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating on array, directly or with `apply_along_axis`, the subarray does not have a `.index` attribute.  So we have to pass an explicit index value to your function:

```
In [248]: def func(i,x):
     ...:    if i//2==0:
     ...:       x = x+10
     ...:    else:
     ...:       x = x+50
     ...:    return x
     ...: 
In [249]: arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
```

`apply` doesn't have a way to add this index, so instead we have to use an explicit iteration.

```
In [250]: np.array([func(i,v) for i,v in enumerate(arr)])
Out[250]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [54, 55],
       [56, 57],
       [58, 59]])
```

replacing // with %

```
In [251]: def func(i,x):
     ...:    if i%2==0:
     ...:       x = x+10
     ...:    else:
     ...:       x = x+50
     ...:    return x
     ...: 
In [252]: np.array([func(i,v) for i,v in enumerate(arr)])
Out[252]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [52, 53],
       [14, 15],
       [56, 57],
       [18, 19]])
```

But a better way is to skip the iteration entirely:

Make an array of the row additions:

```
In [253]: np.where(np.arange(5)%2,10,50)
Out[253]: array([50, 10, 50, 10, 50])
```

apply it via `broadcasting`:

```
In [256]: x+np.where(np.arange(5)%2,50,10)[:,None]
Out[256]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [52, 53],
       [14, 15],
       [56, 57],
       [18, 19]])
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do this

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
     [0, 1, 2, 3]])

y = x.copy() # if you dont wish to modify x
```

for even row index

```
y[::2] = y[::2] + 10
```

and for odd row index

```
y[1::2] = y[1::2] + 50
```

output :

```
array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
       [50, 51, 52, 53]])
```